# How can I set an output value to 2 decimal places in Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net

Im putting together a basic Gross Profit Calculator in Visual Studio and need the output to show as a £ value, ie to 2 decimal places.

I have tried this so far:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", TextBox3.Text = CStr(sale))
```

where TextBox3 is the output for the calculation. However on using this, nothing happens and the box remains empty and I can't work out why!

Comment: Did you mean `TextBox3.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", CStr(sale))`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Visual Studio or C#. The statement is simply wrong and won't even compile. Turning errors off is a *Visual Basic bug*, not a feature

Comment: what type is sale?

Comment: You are dealing with values why use `CStr()`? You can try `FormatNumber(sale,2)`

Comment: BTW `TextBox3.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", sale)` is enough. `CStr` performs a specific type of formatting, while `String.Format` allows for custom formatting

Comment: The expression is of type Boolean.  It is probably False so you'll get 0.  Program for a while with Option Strict On so you can find silly mistakes like this by yourself.  Albeit that it won't catch this one, you'll however learn to not mix data types randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct, re-write your code this way:

```
TextBox3.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", sale)
```

The `String.Format`'s result wasn't being assigned to anything.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is wrong, and besides, `CStr` is just another way to format other types as a string. By using it you *prevent* `String.Format` from doing its job

I think you are looking for

```
TextBox3.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", sale)
```

Furthermore, built-in numeric types override `ToString` and allow custom formatting as well. If `sale` is a float, double or decimal, you can write:

```
TextBox3.Text = sale.ToString("0.00")
```

or

```
TextBox3.Text = sale.ToString("N2")
```